# esri.tasks.GenerateRendererTask for non 10.1 ArcServer

Tags: arcgis-10.0, symbology, rendering, arcgis-server

I wish to use the same features as the `esri.tasks.GenerateRendererTask` but it seems that it can be only used on ArcServer 10.1. Is it possible to achieve the same dynamic natural jenks breaks in the ArcServer 10?

So I will be having a `ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer` and I have to generate the renderer on the fly and the values are also dynamic and not in a fixed range. `esri.tasks.GenerateRendererTask` takes care of it beautifully, is there any other solution to this problem?